# CodeBehind not working after publish

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, publish

Developing on VS 2010, Win 7 Ultimate, ASP.NET/VB.NET 4.0, SQL Server 2008 R2, my web application works flawlessly on both ASP.NET Development Server and IIS 7.5 on local machine. But after publishing to a Win 2008 R2/IIS 7.5/SQL Server 2008 R2 shared hosting space with ASP.NET 4.0 installed, none of my codebehinds are even called.

Symptom is that after click on any button, only a postback occurs and form is re-displayed with no changes or redirection to another page. This occurs in login form and all other forms inside app (I commented authentication code to test this).

The entire code in application contains logging mechanisms to track user actions, but nothing appears in the logging table in hosting database server. No failed authentications and no CAPTCHA mistype errors. None of error messages are loaded from database to be displayed on page.

When I connect the local IIS app to a remote SQL Server database, it works fine, hence no problem with database server.

There are also no errors in the IIS access logs and turning off custom errors in web.config doesn't result in any error page to help detecting point the of failure.

I'm sure something is wrong with IIS configuration on hosting server, but could not figure it out, as it gives me almost no access to critical site configurations (WebsitePanel frontend). 
Unfortunately, hosting technical support personnel are less experienced than needed to fix this and I have to give them direct instructions so that they can fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: PLEASE, paragraphs to break up the text. Nobody is going to want to read this otherwise

Comment: Are there any try/catch blocks logging errors and if so, where do they log? Are you able to use sql server profiler on the database server to see queries being executed and determine if any are from your app?

Comment: @mark-fitzpatrick I neither have permission for ALTER TRACE, nor can have it nor have access to database logs! I requested hosting admin to give me permissions at least to access logs so that I can check. All logs are written to database and because every scenario capable of causing error(s) is pre-checked using If blocks, there are no try/catch block(s). I even checked database connectivity possible issues using try/catch and return message through response, but nothing happened (no errors).

Comment: Try enabling the Trace file in web config. It may help in determining if any of the codebehind is actually running. Also then use the trace.write in some codebehind event just to make sure it's being hit. I often try the OnLoad event, then try to output something to the trace to identify when a button is being hit just to make sure. I recently had an issue where this became crucial to discover that the postback event was occuring without  field data being sent back to the server in post.

Comment: @mark-fitzpatrick I did that (in web.config, for the entire application), but output doesn't show anything regarding button click/postback. This means that button click event is never called. All trace information on output is related to page events, not button event.